# Kubernetes - check if resources defined in YAML file exist

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl

I am creating a bash script to automate certain actions in my cluster. One of the commands is: `kubectl delete -f example.yaml`.

The problem is that when the resources defined in the YAML do not exist, the following error is printed:

```
Error from server (NotFound): error when deleting "example.yaml": deployments.apps "my_app" not found
```

I am looking to add an additional step that first checks whether a set of resources defined in a YAML file exist in the cluster. Is there a command that would allow me to do so?

From the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/), I found:

> ## Compares the current state of the cluster against the state that the cluster would be in if the manifest was applied.
>
> kubectl diff -f ./my-manifest.yaml

but I find it difficult to parse the output that it returns. Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find out if the same object is already present in the cluster as exactly described in the manifest file. you can use the return code of the `kubectl diff` command.

```
Exit status:
 0 No differences were found.
 1 Differences were found. 
 >1 Kubectl or diff failed with an error.
```

Example:

```
kubectl diff -f crazy.yml &>/dev/null
rc=$?
if [ $rc -eq 0 ];then
  echo "Exact Object is already installed on the cluster"
elif [ $rc -eq 1 ];then
  echo "Exact object is not installed, either its not installed or different from the manifest file"
else
  echo "Unable to determine the difference"
fi
```

Alternatively, if you want to really parse the output,  you may use the following env variable to print the diff output in desired format:

> KUBECTL_EXTERNAL_DIFF environment variable can be used to select your
> own diff command. Users can use external commands with params too,